# How to convert HTML to JSON correctly?

Tags: html, arrays, json, flutter, dart

I am having trouble with this in Flutter / Dart.

Currently, I am trying to fetch the data.

```
someHTML = parse(json["somed"]).documentElement!.text;
```

JSON:

```
{"somed":"<h2>Thing<\/h2>\n<h1>Interesting<\/h1>\n<p>Expiring<\/p>\n"}
```

But whatever I do, I can't fetch this properly. If I do:

```
{"somed":"Test"}
```

So, plain text - it works! However, with HTML like H2, I can't get it to work (just throws empty). The HTML I am trying to fetch is from a website and I am trying to get that data.

Anyone who can help here? I tried innerHTML, outerHTML etcetera, but I can't solve it.

Comment: Why are the forward slashes escaped?

Comment: What do you mean? It's just the way it's shown in the JSON data I am trying to fetch. I did not touch the HTML part. Something wrong with the HTML?

Comment: `<h2>Thing<\/h2>\n<h1>Interesting<\/h1>\n<p>Expiring<\/p>\n` isn't valid html

Comment: Any chance you know how I could fix that? I am just trying to fetch the HTML as is - I did not add those slashes myself. It's just plain <h2></h2> in my backend....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Adding `?? ""` did the trick!

```
someHTML = parse(json["somed"] ?? "").documentElement!.text;
```